# forwarding data from one source to another in real time

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, etl

I have a legacy system that is capable of inserting updating data from its database to remote RDBMS (using jdbc driver) in real time. I cannot change the code since I don't have it. 
We are thinking of moving this data to nosql data source like cassandra.

I am thinking of deploying postgres in the middle and pushing it to cassandra or writing it to flat file. Since there are frequent updates I will have to store the data in two database. Is there any ETL process which can listen to sql queries (insert,update,delete) and forward it to different source?

Comment: Have you considered creating a `TRIGGER`. Wrap some business logic in it or invoke a stored procedure from it.

Comment: I have not used Triggers. I think I need to try it.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [bottled water](https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg) to capture changes in postgresql and a create a consumer that would apply those changes to e.g. cassandra.

Comment: Let me check this out.